# build nii file from .mat file with matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I use class `dicom23d` to build a `.mat` file, and now I have one struct with these fields: `volume_image`, `slice_data`, `image_meta_data`, and the type of the `volume_image` is `double`. How could I build `nii` file from it?

```
a=load('123de.mat');
z=a.volume_image;
n12=make_nii(z);
save_nii(n12,'N_144_R2star.nii');
```

When I use `n12=make_nii(z);`, I have an error that I can't use this code for `double`. So I cast it to `unit8` but still have similar error for `unit8`. What should I do?

Comment: is it a typo that your save_nii(nii,'N_144_R2star.nii') line isn't save_nii(n12,'N_144_R2star.nii')

Comment: sorry I made writing mistake,n12=make_nii(z); save_nii(n12,'N_144_R2star.nii');